# The same data in all django templates

Tags: django, templates

I have created my text based game and my game pages have structure like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
// content
{% include 'links.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Now I'm thinking about notifying players about a new message at the top of every page, so I have to update only base.html to show the information, however, I have to add data about new messages to every template before rendering. Maybe is there a quicker way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look into Context Processors -> [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). That's how you automatically add stuff to your templates. Here's a detailed [example](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/) -- it's old, but I think it still works.

Or you can just use [the messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/), which has the appropriate Context Processor implemented and should do what you need here.